# vim disassembles my indentation

Tags: vim, indentation

When i'm in Insert mode at vim, and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> to `paste`  my code to my file, vim disassembles my indentation , Such as:

[image: my indentation has been disassembled by vim]

**Question:** How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Use `"+p` to paste!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vim is acting as if you had typed all of your pasted code by hand, so Vim will add additional indentation and otherwise change whitespace as it normally would, such as with your `autoindent` setting. To paste code in Vim:

1. `:set paste` to enable paste mode.
2. Paste your code.
3. `:set nopaste` to disable paste mode so your normal typing will work as expected again.

And see `:help paste` for more information, including which options are disabled/altered when paste mode is on.

It's possible to set up mappings for this sort of thing if you do it a lot. See `:help imap` for more information on that.

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
:set paste
```

Above code solves your problem.